# Individual product review page

Tags: magento-1.9, review

When user click write a product review then user stay product details page and review section show under product details. I want product review in different page there I show only product name and review information not show product other information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to custome review.xml in your theme.
Please have a look into following step:

Go to review.xml and replace following code

```
<block type="review/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
```

Here, view.phtml file show all informaton in your product. So, make another file like  view_review.phtml file and place it insteadof view.phtml.

```
 <block type="review/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view_review.phtml">
```

So, from view_review.phtml file remove all product information without review Info& product Name. 
I think, it will work :)

Answer (score 1):

By  default,**the write review page is  an individual page**.

Its url should be `www.example.com/review/product/list/id/{ProductId}/#review-form`

Just hit on browser check that  page.

As u want to to show rewrite section on this,then you need to remove customization